# Get clicked Linked ID using JQM pagebeforeshow

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have my JQM index page with the 3 links

```
<div data-role="page" id="index" name="index">
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="b">
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
<h1></h1>
<a href="index.html" data-icon="user" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d">Account</a>
</div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

<table data-role="table"class="ui-responsive" id="myTable">
<td><a href="#choose" id="1" class="add">Join Here</a></td>
<td><a href="#choose" id="2" class="add">Join Here</a></td>
<td><a href="#choose" id="3" class="add">Join Here</a></td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

On The click of Join Here I have another page which is a dialog pop up which is #choose, but the data on this page is determined by which link is clicked before. I can not figure out a way to get that ID to here.

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#choose', function(){
        var id = //ID of clicked link
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/passing-parameters-between-pages-multi-page-model/

For your example, handle the navigation to #choose on click handler of the anchors rather than the href:

```
<table  id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="1" class="add">Join Here</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" id="2" class="add">Join Here</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" id="3" class="add">Join Here</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#index", function(){
    $(".add").on("click", function(){
        var id = this.id;        
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#choose", {theid: id});        
    });
});
```

On click, you get the id of the clicked anchor and then pass it as a parameter in the pagecontainer change method.  To retrieve the id, use pagebeforechange event to read the data options:

```
$(document).on( "pagebeforechange" , function ( event, data ) {
    if ( data.toPage[0].id == "choose" ) {
        var id = data.options.theid;
        console.log(id);
    }
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c1m2e9sx/)**

Comment: Hm it doesnt seem to be firing the click event. I am getting my links from a $.POST() return. Do you think that would effect the click event not firing?

Comment: @pat, if the links are dynamic use event delegation. Simply change the click handler to $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){..., here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c1m2e9sx/1/